# Styled Components Invalid hook call - React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

My styled div:

```
const ProgressBar = ({ value, max, color, width }) => {
       return (
          <Container color={color} width={width}>
             <progress value={value} max={max} data-label={value + "/" + max} />
             <span className="card-title mt-0">{parseFloat((value / max) * 100).toFixed(2)}%</span>
          </Container>
       )
    };
```

I call this div:

```
import ProgressBar from '../shared/ProgressBar'
    <div className="col-md-9">
       <ProgressBar value={0} max={100} />
    </div>
```

I use this axios-route to set the responseData, which will be used to fill the values of the ProgressBar

```
 scrapeStatusHandler = () => {
      user_id = 1
      trackPromise(
         axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/scraper_status', user_id)
            .then(res => {
               this.setState({
                  responseData: {
                     
                  }
               })
            }));
   }
```

However, I'm still getting the Invalid hook call error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see any hooks in the provided code. Can you show your hooks?

Comment: Please provide the relevant hooks code

Comment: @mousetail added the hook i guess? I'm not 100% sure

Comment: That looks like a class component, not a hook. You shouldn't mix class and function components

Comment: There are no hooks being used in what you posted. By convention, all hooks start with 'use': like useState, useReducer, useMemo, etc. There isn't enough here for us to say what the problem is. Maybe in `trackPromise`?

Comment: I understand! This makes me even more confused, I use the ProgressBar component in my view, and I use that state to fill the attributes of this progressbar. Why would I be getting a hook error then?

Comment: @JaredSmith even with the trackPromise removed it gives the error

Comment: @BorisWinter you are probably using a third-party library function that calls a hook in your class component, which you are not allowed to do (hooks can only be called from function components or other hooks). Or maybe in a callback (hooks must be unconditionally rendered). But again, you haven't given us enough code to say. Create a minimal reproduction case that shows the problem (DO NOT dump your entire website on us please) and post it.

Comment: @JaredSmith thank you for the patience, will do at a later point today!

Comment: any updates on this? @BorisWinter